# How to make SwiftUI's NavigationView remember the state of its members in macOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, swiftui, state, navigationview

I have implemented a SwiftUI `NavigationView` in macOS as follows:

```swift
struct App1: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView {
                SideBar()
                Text("SCREEN 1")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `SideBar()` is a list of navigation links as follows:

```swift
struct SideBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            NavigationLink(destination: SomeListView1()){
                Text("Item1")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: SomeListView2()){
                Text("Item2")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: SomeListView3()){
                Text("Item3")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where `SomeListViewn()` contains a list of items.

When I click different navigation links in the side bar, the related views are reloaded each time. For example, if I was to click `Item1` and scroll to the bottom of the list of items in `SomeListView1()`, then switch to `Item2` and back to `Item1`, `SomeListView1()` is reloaded, i.e., it forgets its scroll position and re-initialises the view. I want the navigation views to remember their state so when you switch to different items in the sidebar and switch back, you can continue where you left off.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Save the state of some view in your model or appstorage var so on .onAppear you could eventually go back to previous position.

Comment: Use SceneStorage not AppStorage. You are on MacOS if you use app storage and the user opens another window all the windows will change and only display the same thing.

Comment: by "saving the state" do you mean saving the scroll position? and then jumping to it every time the screen is opened?

Comment: @loremipsum : thanks for the info, I am more use to iOS.

Comment: @PtitXav my comment applies to iPadOS as well. Anywhere where multiple windows are supported.

Comment: @PtitXav can you please explain how to "save the state" of some view? SceneStorage seems to be only compatible with primitive types and not views

Comment: @TylerDurden you save the [`NavigationLink<V>(LocalizedStringKey, tag: V, selection: Binding<V?>, destination: () -> Destination)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink) Look at [Restoring your app's state with SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/restoring_your_app_s_state_with_swiftui)

Comment: @loremipsum can you please write an answer which shows how to save the NavigationLink? Ive read the link you provided but scene storage can only be used for plist data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=Scenestorage%20navigationlink

Comment: ok. im not looking to remember the selection of a list. I want to stop the entire view from reloading.

Comment: You can't stop reloading, reloading is 100% at the discretion of SwiftUI the only thing you can do is "recover" as you see would like the user experience to be, and/or learns the basics of SwiftUI to limit reloading. There are many ways of doing that. `@SceneStorage` is the most practical, You can also make CoreData objects "view models" so you have persistence for the `selection`, but this is very involved and in most cases overkill. A `@StateObject` might work as well depending on the use case, and the position of the object.

Comment: We can't help you anymore with the code you have provided. If `@State` and `@StateObject` aren't working to preserve state naturally you are likely applying some workaround to invalidate the identify of the View. Watch Demystifying SwiftUI from WWDC21

Comment: I think I have misunderstood how the NavigationView works in macOS. I wanted it to work like the TabView in iOS, where if I click different tabs, I can return to a tab with its View in the same state it was left in without having to use SceneStorage or AppStorage.